# Storing claims on cookie while redirecting to other URL and also without identity authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, nuxt.js, asp.net-core-3.1, claims-based-identity, claims

I just need advise if this is feasible. I am developing an authorization for my Shopify app and I need to somewhat store the access token from shopify auth for future verification of my front-end app.

So the first end-point the shopify is calling is this one:

```
    [HttpGet("install")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Install()
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var queryString = Request.QueryString.Value;
                var isValid = _shopifyService.VerifyRequest(queryString);

                if (isValid)
                {
                    var shopifyUrl = Request.Query["shop"];
                    var authUrl = _shopifyService.BuildAuthUrl(shopifyUrl,
                        $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.Value}/api/shopify/authorize",
                        Program.Settings.Shopify.AuthorizationScope);

                    return Redirect(authUrl);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exceptionMessage = await ApiHelpers.GetErrors(ex, _localizer).ConfigureAwait(false);
            ModelState.AddModelError(new ValidationResult(exceptionMessage));
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(new ValidationResult(_localizer["InvalidAuthStore"]));
        return BadRequest(ModelState.GetErrors());
    }
```

This works fine and the result of this api call will actually redirect to same link to my api, but this one will authorize the app:

```
    [HttpGet("authorize")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AuthorizeStore()
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var code = Request.Query["code"];
                var shopifyUrl = Request.Query["shop"];

                var accessToken = await _shopifyService.AuthorizeStore(code, shopifyUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);

                var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Constants.Claims.AccessToken, accessToken));

                // genereate the new ClaimsPrincipal
                var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                // store the original tokens in the AuthenticationProperties
                var props = new AuthenticationProperties {
                    AllowRefresh = true,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                    IsPersistent = false,
                    IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                };

                // sign in using the built-in Authentication Manager and ClaimsPrincipal
                // this will create a cookie as defined in CookieAuthentication middleware
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal, props).ConfigureAwait(false);


                Uri uri = new Uri($"{Program.Settings.Shopify.RedirectUrl}?token={accessToken}");
                return Redirect(uri.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exceptionMessage = await ApiHelpers.GetErrors(ex, _localizer).ConfigureAwait(false);
            ModelState.AddModelError(new ValidationResult(exceptionMessage));
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(new ValidationResult(_localizer["InvalidAuthStore"]));
        return BadRequest(ModelState.GetErrors());
    }
```

So the above api will authorize my app in shopify and will return an access token. The accessToken is the one I want to save in the claims identity with Cookie authentication type(this is without authorizing user credentials). Still no errors at that point and after calling the `HttpContext.SignInAsync` function, I can still view using debugger the newly added claims.

As, you can see in the code, after assigning claims, I call to redirect the app to front-end link(Note: front-end and back-end has different url)

In my front-end app, I have a Nuxt middleware that I put a logic to check the token received from back-end since I only pass the token to the front-end app using query params. Here's my middleware code:

```
export default function ({ app, route, next, store, error, req }) {
  if (process.browser) {
    const shopifyAccessToken = store.get('cache/shopifyAccessToken', null)

    if (!shopifyAccessToken && route.query.token) {
      // if has token on query params but not yet in cache, store token and redirect
      store.set('cache/shopifyAccessToken', route.query.token)
      app.router.push({
        path: '/',
        query: {}
      })

      // verify access token on the route
      app.$axios
        .get(`/shopify/verifyaccess/${route.query.token}`)
        .catch((err) => {
          error(err)
        })
    } else if (!shopifyAccessToken && !route.query.token) {
      // if does not have both, throw error
      error({
        statusCode: 401,
        message: 'Unauthorized access to this app'
      })
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```

In my middleware, when the route has query params equal to `token=` It calls another api to verify the accessToken saved in my claims identity:

```
    [HttpGet("verifyaccess/{accessToken}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> VerifyAccess(string accessToken)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var principal = HttpContext.User;
                if (principal?.Claims == null)
                    return Unauthorized(_localizer["NotAuthenticated"]);

                var accessTokenClaim = principal.FindFirstValue(Constants.Claims.AccessToken);

                if (accessToken == accessTokenClaim)
                {
                    return Ok();
                } 
                else
                {
                    return Unauthorized(_localizer["NotAuthenticated"]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exceptionMessage = await ApiHelpers.GetErrors(ex, _localizer).ConfigureAwait(false);
            ModelState.AddModelError(new ValidationResult(exceptionMessage));
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(new ValidationResult(_localizer["InvalidAuthStore"]));
        return BadRequest(ModelState.GetErrors());
    }
```

Looking at the code above, it always fails me because the claims identity that I saved on the `authorize` endpoint was not there or in short the ClaimsIdentity is always empty.

Here's how I register the Cookie config:

```
    private void ConfigureAuthCookie(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(option =>
        {
            option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            option.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn = false;
        })
        .AddCookie(options => {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.Cookie.Name = "shopifytoken";
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
    }
```

and I also put a `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()` on my Startup.Configure

Please let me know if this seems confusing so I can revised it. My main goal here is to be able to access that accessToken that I saved in the ClaimsIdentity so that I can verify the token. The reason why I did this because currently the shopify does not have an API for verifying access token. So when a user access my app link like this one `http://example.com/?token=<any incorrect token>` then they can already access my app.

Comment: Try to set a break point in your Middleware to check whether the HttpContext.User is null or just the Claims is null? If they all are null, check the code in the Configure method make sure that call the middleware in the order like below: UseRouting, UseAuthentication, UseAuthorization, and UseEndpoints. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services

Comment: User was not null but only the claims @ZhiLv